# How to use field of pivot table

Tags: laravel, relationship

I've two tables user and product, along with their relationship user_product. The relationship table contains an extra field category. Now I want to find
the number of products selected by a user of a particular category.

I've done it in my page through coding. Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

> How to use field of pivot table?

you can use `withPivot`

Ex:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Role')->withPivot('foo', 'bar');
```